# Why am I suddenly getting an unauthorized access error?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, 2007

I've been a long time lurker but finally had to post this, I've got several site collections on my server. Each with their own port. We had a contractor come in and set up one of the site collections with SSL/alternate access mapping and everything was working great. I'm not sure if someone in my department was tweaking settings or what happend but now the site wont allow me to sign in to make changes. As soon as I click sign-in it immediately goes to a http 401.1 Unauthorized access (I don't even have a chance to submit my credentials). I've looked for errors and and haven't seen anything in regards to this. I went to central admin and it appears the only difference between this site collection and the others is that it is different in the Alternate access mappings.

You can see for yourself at the bottom: https://apply.alaskapacific.edu/  at the bottom because as I stated it doesn't even require credentials to kick up this error.

EDIT: It does prompt for credentials, once it has it it doesn't pass it through.

Comment: When I access the link, it asks for credentials - sure the issue isn't just located to your work's network?

Comment: I'll have to check it offsite I guess, I never thought to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get authenticated for credentials at all.  I wonder if your problem has been resolved already?  If not, I wonder if your credentials have been cached in your Windows password store.  If so, you may need to clear it out to see the authentication prompt again.

Comment: I don't think they're cached, but you guys are making me wonder if there is a wrong internal configure problem. I'll have to check it offsite.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't prompting me, I had added the URL to the trusted sites in trying to troubleshoot and it automatically was sending my credentials.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.  Thanks for posting your solution.  I suggest you add it as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Comment: The problem still remains in that it wont accept my credentials. It only goes to the http 401.1 IIS error, it's almost as if Sharepoint and IIS aren't working together for the authentication. If it were a sharepoint authentication issue it should be giving me a sharepoint error. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Have you checked it from off-site yet? It sounds like a problem with your internal DNS.

Comment: Yes, I checked offsite and it is still the same issue. It will prompt and I enter my user credentials just like I do on all the other site collections and instead of accepting the credentials it goes to the IIS error.

Comment: Do you have anything in your local hosts file on your computer that could be causing this?  For that matter, have you tried it from another computer?  It's strange that when James and I try it we aren't prompted.

Comment: James said he was prompted, and I also was prompted offsite. I'm curious why you aren't getting prompted?

Comment: Well, after rereading your original post, I can explain why I wasn't getting prompted.  Minor detail: I was clicking on the apply link instead of the sign in link.  Sorry about that.  Is anyone able to authenticate?  Can you authenticate from a browser on the server itself?  Be sure you domain qualify the username.  Also, if you can authenticate from the server but not from a client then it may be the user with which you are running the SharePoint service jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar problem with Access denied on some actions. I solved it with correct specification of external mapping URL on SP. Maybe it will help you as well.